# Javascript prime numbers within a range program not displaying results

Tags: javascript, html

My program is currently not generating any text output into its designated HTML element. It only says "Prime Time assignment:"

```js
var numOne = Number(prompt("Please enter the first whole number to begin the range you'd like to explore."));
var numTwo = Number(prompt("Enter the second whole number to conclude the range you'd like to explore. Hint: Second choice > first."));

if (numOne < numTwo && Number.isInteger(numOne) && Number.isInteger(numTwo)) {
  for (; numOne <= numTwo; numOne++) {
    for (i = 2; numOne <= i; i++) {
      if (numOne % i == 0) {
        break;
      }

      if (numOne == i) {
        document.getElementById("primeTime").innerHTML += numOne + " is a prime number.";
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  window.alert("Please reload the webpage and try again. Error code: User error.");
}
```

```html
<!-- Prime Time Assignment -->
<p id="primeTime"> Prime Time assignment: <br/></p>
```

Comment: `for(i = 2; numOne <= i; i++) {` - think about this ... if you enter a range of 10 to 20 ... how many times will this loop iterate?

Comment: perhaps you meant `for(i = 2; numOne > i; i++) {` ( not `>=` by the way ) and `if (numOne == i + 1) {`

Comment: thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for the inner loop is wrong, you need **>=** and your *if (numOne == i)* is at the wrong place:

```
  var numOne = Number(prompt("Please enter the first whole number to begin the range you'd like to explore."));
  var numTwo = Number(prompt("Enter the second whole number to conclude the range you'd like to explore. Hint: Second choice > first."));

  if (numOne < numTwo && Number.isInteger(numOne) && Number.isInteger(numTwo)) {
    for(; numOne <= numTwo; numOne++) {
      for(var i = 2; numOne >= i; i++) {
        if (numOne == i) {
          document.getElementById("primeTime").innerHTML += numOne + " is a prime number.";
        }  

        if (numOne % i == 0) { 
             break;
        }
      }
    }         
  }
  else {
    window.alert("Please reload the webpage and try again. Error code: User error.");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. As I expected it was something stupid I should have picked up one.

Comment: Please don't use this code for large numbers - entering a range 100,000,000 to 100,000,100 takes 12 seconds to find 6 primes - even just a slightly better algorithm (no higher math involved) can do the same range in 14**milli**seconds (so, almost 1000 times faster)